# PHP IIS JavaScript Not inserting Row count more then 28 in Mysql Data base Win Server 2012

Tags: javascript, php, iis

I am trying to insert 150 rows of data via ajax to mysql database using PHP on Windows Server 2012.

On my local Win 7 Machine, when i insert 150 rows of data - it is working fine.

But same on server: Only 28 rows are getting inserted and rest of them do not get inserted. I think it stops receiving the data after certain period i have made changes in PHP.ini too

```
max_execution_time = 36000
max_input_time = 36000
max_input_vars = 250000
memory_limit = 256M
post_max_size = 828M
```

I have same replica of DB, PHP, on both server and local - But during insert it stops in certain period of receiving the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem only happens when you use PHP to upload a file.  When you upload a file, PHP sends the file to a temporary directory on the hard drive (for me it is C:\Windows\Temp) and then copies it over to it’s intended directory.  Once the file has landed in the temporary directory, it is assigned the permissions of that directory. The problem is when Windows copies that file, it keeps the temporary directory’s permissions and doesn’t inherit your web directory’s permissions.

- In PHP.ini file, Find for upload_tmp_dir
- give a directory path which as read/write permission
- example: upload_tmp_dir= E:\tmp
- Save php.ini
- restart IIS

Share if this worked !